# Expo notifications working locally when running expo, but not working after pushing new build to testflight

Tags: react-native, push-notification, expo

In my react native expo app, the push-notifications work locally, and I have created a button to trigger this notification. When I create a dev-build using eas for android the notifications do not come through in production on the APK. Its the same case when I have made a push to testflight. I have confirmed that a valid expo token is being used and am storing that in my zuzstand store.

I am using sdkVersion: '47.0.0',

Any guidance will be appreciated, just need to get notifications working in my builds outside of the expo app!

I followed the official [expo documentation for push notifications](https://docs.expo.dev/push-notifications/push-notifications-setup/) step by step, which included setting up the firebase console as well as uploading the FCM key to my expo.dev creds.

This is the code that I tried that is linked to the button on my frontend. Works locally, but not in production.

```js
export async function sendPushNotification(expoPushToken) {
  const message = {
    to: expoPushToken,
    sound: "default",
    title: "Welcome",
    body: "Body text",
    data: { someData: "goes here" },
  };

  await fetch("https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(message),
  });
}
```

Comment: I am struggling with the same issue. Did you figure out anything?

Answer (score 0):

Once the app is pushed to production. Allow notification for the app on your android device. It should be a permissions issue.